# how to export armatures

Tags: python, export, armature

I used to export armatures in 2.49 using the following code:

```
# armature
for bone in data.bones.values():
    pariente = bone.parent
    if (pariente):
        matriz_p = Blender.Mathutils.Matrix(pariente.matrix['ARMATURESPACE'])

    matriz = Blender.Mathutils.Matrix(bone.matrix['ARMATURESPACE'])
    if (pariente):
        matriz = matriz*matriz_p.invert()

    trans = matriz.translationPart()
    rot = matriz.toQuat()
    rot = rot.normalize()

    buf = "\n" + str(trans.x) + " " + str(trans.y) + " " + str(trans.z)
    buf += "\n" + str(rot.x) + " " + str(rot.y) + " " + str(rot.z) + " " + str(rot.w)
    file.write(buf)


#keyframes
for bone in pose.bones.values():        

        buf = "\n" + str(bone.loc.x) + " " + str(bone.loc.y) + " " + str(bone.loc.z)
        buf += "\n" + str(bone.quat.x) + " " + str(bone.quat.y) + " " + str(bone.quat.z) + " " + str(bone.quat.w)
        buf += "\n" + str(bone.size.x) + " " + str(bone.size.y) + " " + str(bone.size.z)            

        file.write(buf)
```

I tried to convert it for use in 2.69 and i got this:

```
for bone in obj.data.bones:
pariente = bone.parent

if (pariente):
    matriz_p = mathutils.Matrix(pariente.matrix_local)

matriz = mathutils.Matrix(bone.matrix_local)
if (pariente):
    matriz_p_inv = matriz_p
    matriz_p_inv.invert()
    matriz = matriz_p_inv * matriz

trans = matriz.to_translation()
rot =  matriz.to_quaternion()
rot.normalize()

buf = str(trans.x) + " " + str(trans.y) + " " + str(trans.z) + "\n"
buf += str(rot.x) + " " + str(rot.y) + " " + str(rot.z) + " " + str(rot.w) + "\n"
file.write(buf)

buf = str( int(obj.animation_data.action.frame_range[1]) ) + "\n"
file.write(buf)

Scene = bpy.context.scene

for bone in obj.pose.bones:
for Frame in range( int(obj.animation_data.action.frame_range[0]), int(obj.animation_data.action.frame_range[1]) + 1 ):
    Scene.frame_set(Frame)

    pariente = bone.parent
    if (pariente):
        matriz_p = mathutils.Matrix(pariente.matrix_channel)

    matriz_l = mathutils.Matrix(bone.bone.matrix_local)
    matriz_l.invert()
    matriz = mathutils.Matrix(bone.matrix)
    if (pariente):
        matriz_p_inv = matriz_p
        matriz_p_inv.invert()
        matriz = (matriz_l*matriz_p_inv) * matriz
    else:
        matriz = matriz_l * matriz

    trans = matriz.to_translation()
    rot =  matriz.to_quaternion()
    rot.normalize()

    buf = str(trans.x) + " " + str(trans.y) + " " + str(trans.z) + "\n"
    buf += str(rot.x) + " " + str(rot.y) + " " + str(rot.z) + " " + str(rot.w) + "\n"
    file.write(buf)
```

I based it on the way the milkshape exporter works, but it seems the keyframe matrices are wrong because it gives me an incorrect rotation and scale.

So my question is: how do i get the same pose matrix data as 2.49 in 2.69?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post.

Comment: The order matters in vector/matrix multipliction, and there was a change in 2.62 from column-major to row-major IIRC. Maybe that is causing you trouble? BTW: you can do this `buf = "\n" + str(bone.loc.x) + " " + str(bone.loc.y) + " " + str(bone.loc.z)` more readable like `buf = "\n%s %s %s" % bone.loc[:]` (although I recommend `%f`, e.g. `%.6f` to always use 6 decimal places).

Comment: Thanks! I'm not very good with python and i didn't know you could format the text output, so thanks for that again. I tried switching the order of the multiplications but it just got worse. Also i'm not really sure what is the difference between "matrix_channel", "matrix_basis" and "matrix" in the pose bones. I also tried exchanging them but it didn't work either.

Comment: The matrix attribute explanations here: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_9/bpy.types.PoseBone.html#bpy.types.PoseBone.matrix

Comment: I solved it. The problem wasn't in the matrices but in the model's vertex weights. Thanks anyway.