# Is it possible to record/save the the Joint positions information (from the rig) of an animation?

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging

Is there any way to save the the Joint positions information ? For eg:from the rig, how to get 3d position of the  body joins like neck, shoulder,knee,..etc of an animated character in Blender and how to save them?  I need the positions of the joints of interests saved in a file, corresponding to each frame.

Comment: Export the animation as FBX. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I need the positions of the joints of interests marked in a file(or image file), corresponding to each frame.

Comment: I am sorry, is there something wrong with my question?

Comment: @p.Neu python scripting could help (I'm not an expert), as in this other question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/how-to-export-armatures